# Why is the 'mod' function in LaTeX so wide? (extra space on the left of it)

Tags: spacing

When trying to use the *mod* function that LaTeX offers, I always meet a problem: it seems to have a space or two in front of it that I can't delete without `\hspace`. Why is that and how can I fix it?

What shows up: `$(\mod n)$`

[image]

What I want: `$(\hspace{-0.3cm}\mod n)$`

[image]

Answer (score 39, accepted):

See section 5.2 of the [`amsmath` manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) for the details of `\mod` and related commands (`\mod`, `\pmod`, `\bmod`, `\pod`) but the short version is that if you want parens around it, you should use `\pmod`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  1+1 \equiv 0 \pmod{2}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]
*(Taken from Version 2.1)*

Comment: +1: I took the liberty to modify your answer.

Comment: Ohhh do I have to import amsmath every time? Is it supported natively in LaTeX? btw why this TeX community doesn't support LaTeX in the questions and answers :/

Comment: @CELLSecret any latex document with a serious amount of math should load amsmath, it is the core latex math support, part of the "required" package distribution, that said, as it says in the quote above, `\pmod`` is defined in the format, not in `amsmath`. We don't support mathjax on this site _because_ this is about TeX, see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1272/why-doesnt-maths-render-as-maths

Comment: `\pmod`, `\bmod` etc. macros are defined in plain TeX too. We need not LaTeX.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think you put the \` in the wrong place lol

Comment: This answer has literally changed my life.